# Proguard issue:not opening the app when using fragments?

Tags: android, proguard

i am integrated my app  with ABS & i used proguard and published in google play .i tested in 4.0.4 ,its works fine.now i am getting error message from users.its not working 2.2,2.3 devices.

stack trace:

```
   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.phoneix.divya.GalleryActivity.getActionBar
  at com.phoneix.divya.GalleryActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Proguard-project.txt

```
   -dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
  -dontwarn android.support.**
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; } 
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; } 
  -keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; } 
 -keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; } 
  -keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class * extends android.view.View
 -keep public class * extends android.view.ViewGroup
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```